# Нахождение расстояния между элементами массива

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

Представьте 2х мерный массив. Массив визуализируется графически где каждый элемент - клетка, и будем считать что мы можем выделять элементы (клетки). Допустим, мы выделили 0вой элемент, т.е. левый верхний угол (0, 0). Теперь надо сделать так, чтобы дальше можно было выбирать элементы, до которых 'расстояние' меньше X, т.е. между первоначально выделенным элементом и новым должно быть меньше или равно X клеток.

Понимаю, что подобное объяснение некорректно, так как это уже поиск пути и т.п. Но все же, как можно подобное реализовать. Короче говоря, надо чтобы между первой выделенной клеткой и новыми расстояние было ограничено.

Comment: Такиа в чем собственно проблема, что вызывает затруднения?

Comment: @Kromster Как рассчитать количество клеток между первоначальной и новой выделенной (проще говоря между 2 элементами массива)

Comment: Вроде неплохо должен подойти [волновой алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9B%D0%B8) (по крайней мере его идея) - создаете множество посещенных вершин, производите X итераций, на каждой итерации добавляете всех соседей всех посещенных вершин в множество. В конце множество будет содержать все вершины, до которых можно добраться из начальной за Х или менее шагов. (по сути, это аналог поиска в ширину в графе)

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под количеством клеток между двумя другими?

Comment: @АндрейNOP наверное количество клеток в самом коротком маршруте между 2 клетками. Я уже понял что тут только с графами и алгоритмами поиска пути можно обойтись.

Comment: Пока ни из чего не следует, что нужны "графы и алгоритмы поиска пути". Чем, например, не подходит Манхэттенское расстояние `d = abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)`?

Comment: А как маршрут-то можно строить? По любой линии? Или может из клетки можно переходить только в клетку имеющую с текущей общую сторону? Или как?

Comment: @the_anonymous, вы так пишете, как будто нам это должно быть очевидно то, что вы у себя в голове держите.